# When to use Delegate in C#, Why and does it work on a different thread?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I know this question have been asked a lot, but I need one answer for all what I asked in a very practical way and preferably with code examples.
When Should I use delegate methods in C#?
How to use it?
Why should I use it?
what does it has to do with Multi threading?

Any answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A delegate is basically a method pointer. It has a reference to the method, and its object (unless it's a static method, of course).

You use a delegate whenever you need to call a method but the code calling it doesn't know which method it is. The most common reason is that the code calling the method was made before the method, e.g. a library method like `List<T>.Sort(comparison)`.

Delegates doesn't call the method on a different thread, it's called on the same thread as the code using the delegate. When a method is called on a different thread it's because the code using the delegate is already running on a different thread, or specifically starts a new thread for the method.

Answer (score 0):

Delegate is a function pointer which points to any function like in C. You can pass delegate as parameter to some other function.

you can use this for call back functions, threads etc.

For more information look in to this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) Link

Answer (score 0):

with regards to multithreading Delegate.BeginInvoke is used to invoke a method in a background thread. Delegates are also used to pass function references to other multithreading constructs like ThreadPool backgroundworker etc..